# Change font style only from the caption in a TListView in vsReport mode

Tags: delphi, vcl, tlistview

I have 3 columns in a `TListView` in `vsReport` mode, with the `Checkboxes` property enabled. I'd like to make **only** the caption font bold when an item is checked. I tried using the `OnCustomDrawItem` event but it makes all the rows bold.

```
procedure TfrmMain.lvwCompsCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  if (Item.Checked) then
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold]
  else
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
end;
```

I cannot find in method `OnCustomDrawItem` how to isolate the first column (caption). So I also tried to use the `OnCustomDrawSubItem` event, to "remove" the bold style from the subitems, without success.

```
procedure TfrmMain.lvwCompsCustomDrawSubItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; SubItem: Integer; State: TCustomDrawState;
  var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  if (SubItem > 0) then
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
end;
```

Please, can someone help me?

Comment: Owner-drawing in a `TListView` is a bit honky. In my project, I had to use the `OnAdvancedCustomDrawItem` and `OnAdvanceCustomDrawSubItem` events, drawing only in the `cdPrePaint` stage, and manually call the `TListView.Font.OnChange` event handler in the `OnAdvanceCustomDrawSubItem` event after making changes to the `Sender.Canvas.Font` or else subsequent columns would not draw correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you for editing the question, english is not my first language. Also thank you for the comment, I will try to apply your suggestions!

Comment: When mr. Lebeau tells something is "honky" (even though I do not know what this means) I get worried... I tried his suggestions, but in my case they didn't work. So I decided to give up and used a workaround... Thank you!

Comment: I meant wonky (meaning "not functioning correctly; faulty"), not honky. Stupid autocorrect.

Comment: I got the ideia :) Thanks!!